# Can one change the (ugly) MinionPro apostrophe kerning value with a macro?

Tags: kerning, minionpro

If we compare these three text lines

```
Linné's naming scheme.

{Linné'}s naming scheme.

{{Linné}'}s naming scheme.
```

typeset them in MinionPro, and look at the final pdf

[image]

we note that only the last line leads to a barely acceptable result. The reason: MinionPro has **wrong** apostrophe kerning settings. (In fact, the settings are so bad that languages with many apostrophes, such as French, cannot be typeset with the standard MinionPro package at all.)

The best solution would be to improve MinionPro. But the package is not maintained, unfortunately. There exists an underground apostrophe-friendly version of MinionPro, but it is a hack.

Is there a way to adjust the kerning of the apostrophe **within a latex macro**? (I use the dvi-ps-pdf route, with MinionPro and microtype, pdflatex and texlive 2014; the fonts are .pfb, thus NOT opentype, but postscript.)

I tried the suggestion

```
\SetExtraKerning
  [ unit     = space   ]
  { encoding = {OT1,T1,LY1} }
  {
    '  = {3000, }
  }
```

but with no success.

P.S A minimal example is this:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      
\usepackage{MinionPro}      
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\begin{document}

Linné's naming scheme.

{Linné'}s naming scheme.

{{Linné}'}s naming scheme.

\end{document}
```

P.P.S. There is a related, but smaller issue with the kerning of the glyph " (double quote) in MinionPro.

Comment: Which TeX engine do you use, and what's the name of the font file that contains the Minion Pro font -- is it an OpenType font? It would be helpful if you expanded your code snippets into an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your result and a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A solution is to load `MinionPro` with the option `loosequotes`

```
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

Linné's naming scheme.

{Linné'}s naming scheme.

{{Linné}'}s naming scheme.

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the `MinionPro` manual:

> `loosequotes`
>
> The quote signs of MinionPro are set rather tight. This can lead
>   to undesirable spacing for apostrophes. The `loosequotes` option slightly increases the side bearings of quotes.
>   This option requires pdfTEX 1.40 and microtype 2.0. Beware
>   that this option prevents hyphenation of words containing apostrophes. Such words will require explicit hyphenation commands `\-` .

If you want to use the `\SetExtraKerning` feature you have to load `microtype` with the option `kerning=true`

```
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\SetExtraKerning
  [ unit     = space   ]
  { encoding = {OT1,T1,LY1} }
  {
    '  = {3000, }
  }

\begin{document}

Linné's naming scheme.

{Linné'}s naming scheme.

{{Linné}'}s naming scheme.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, if you want to change both the spacing before and after that character, use something like

```
\SetExtraKerning
  [ unit     = space   ]
  { encoding = {OT1,T1,LY1} }
  {
    '  = {500, 400}
  }
```

where `500` denotes the spacing *before* and `400` the spacing *after* the character  (in thousandths of `1em`).

Comment: True, but even that is often tight (I had forgotten to mention this); is there a way to get the command \SetExtraKerning to work properly?

Comment: @MotionMountain See the edit.

Comment: Thank you! To complete the answer for future generations: by adding a number AFTER the expression 3000, - such as in 3000,1000 - we can also increase the kerning AFTER the apostrophe.

Comment: @MotionMountain You're welcome.

Comment: But how does one then take care of this case: He said ``Hallo". Now the left and the right quotation marks differ...

Comment: @MotionMountain Please ask a follow-up question for this.