# Looking for Global Solution to Insufficient Apostrophe Kerning with Cabin

Tags: kerning, definition, apostrophe, define, cabin

In [How to Increase the Space Between a Letter and Its Apostrophe with Cabin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671708/how-to-increase-the-space-between-a-letter-and-its-apostrophe-with-cabin), it was suggested that in order to increase the kerning between a letter and the adjoining apostrophe, one may use

`\mbox{'}` in place of the apostrophe.

This works nicely, but

QUESTION: I would like to know if it is possible to redefine the apostrophe on a global basis so that `\mbox{'}` is produced whenever `'`, or perhaps, a substitute symbol is typed. I say, a different symbol, since it would not be desirable to doubly display `\mbox{'}` if say, the double quotes `''` were intended.

Thank you.

Comment: The solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222493/208544) with microtype and `\SetExtraKerning` seems to work for me, at least regarding spacing